# want to define foreign key as a part of primary key in mysql database table

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key

there is my queries. why i am getting error?

```
CREATE TABLE researcher(
    RID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(30),
    LAST_NAME VARCHAR(30),
    COUNTRY VARCHAR(30),
    WORKING_YEAR INT,
    Experience INT DEFAULT 0,
    CURRENT_WORK VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT "no entry",
    CONSTRAINT con1 PRIMARY KEY(RID)
)
```

then

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS reviews
(
    RID INT,
    REVIEW_ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    REVIEW_TIME TIMESTAMP DEFAULT "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
    CONSTRAINT for3 FOREIGN KEY(RID) REFERENCES researcher(RID),
    CONSTRAINT con5 PRIMARY KEY(RID, REVIEW_ID)
 )
```

then  MySQL said:

```
#1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key
```

where is my fault?

Comment: I suggest you create the primary key on review id and create a UNIQUE key on rid,review_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If use AUTO_INCREMENT , it need to provide primary key on it

example

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS reviews
(
    RID INT,
    REVIEW_ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    REVIEW_TIME TIMESTAMP DEFAULT "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
    CONSTRAINT for3 FOREIGN KEY(RID) REFERENCES researcher(RID),
    CONSTRAINT con5 PRIMARY KEY(REVIEW_ID)
)
```

Comment: yes i have also added it. i want to add a primary key by join two attribute

Comment: Not strictly true you could have a compound primary as long as the first node is the auto_increment column for example CONSTRAINT con5 PRIMARY KEY(REVIEW_ID, rid) is syntactically and functionally correct (but maybe not what op needs or wants)